# How do you change dates in a data frame?

Tags: r, date

In a data frame that I've called into R, I'm trying to change the dates listed to a different date. For example, I want `2020-06-04` to become `2020-06-03`.

Below is code that I've tried to write in order to do this, but haven't succeeded.

I also did this to the data frame prior:

```
AbsoluteCover$Date <- as.Date(AbsoluteCover$Date,
                   format = "%m/%d/%y")
```

1:

```
AC <- mutate(AbsoluteCover, NewDate = c("2020-06-04" == "2020-06-03" & "2020-06-19" == "2020-06-18" & "2020-07-12" == "2020-07-28"))
```

This just creates a new column called "NewDate" but with all FALSE in the cells. This outcome makes sense, but it's not what I want.

2:

```
AC <- AbsoluteCover %>% mutate(Date, "2020-06-04" == "2020-06-03" & "2020-06-19" == "2020-06-18" & "2020-07-12" == "2020-07-28")
```

This does the same thing as 1 above.

3:

```
AC <- replace(AbsoluteCover$Date, c("2020-06-04", "2020-06-19", "2020-07-12"), c("2020-06-03", "2020-06-18", "2020-07-28"))
```

This just returns a data frame with one column with dates.

Here is an example of my data frame:

```
dput(head(AbsoluteCover))
structure(list(Plot = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A2"), 
    Date = structure(c(18417, 18432, 18455, 18417, 18432, 18455
    ), class = "Date"), Cover = c(12L, 34L, 17L, 2L, 50L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(
    Plot = c("A1", "A2"), .rows = list(1:3, 4:6)), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you haven't provided a sample dataframe, I have worked out the example using a test dataset.

You can use the `which` function to select the rows based on condition

```r
dates = c(as.Date('2020-06-04'), as.Date('2020-01-03'))
df = data.frame('a' = sample(dates, 15, replace= TRUE))
df
#>             a
#> 1  2020-01-03
#> 2  2020-06-04
#> 3  2020-06-04
#> 4  2020-01-03
#> 5  2020-06-04
#> 6  2020-06-04
#> 7  2020-01-03
#> 8  2020-06-04
#> 9  2020-01-03
#> 10 2020-01-03
#> 11 2020-01-03
#> 12 2020-01-03
#> 13 2020-01-03
#> 14 2020-06-04
#> 15 2020-06-04
df[which(df$a == as.Date('2020-06-04')), 'a'] = as.Date('2020-06-03')
df
#>             a
#> 1  2020-01-03
#> 2  2020-06-03
#> 3  2020-06-03
#> 4  2020-01-03
#> 5  2020-06-03
#> 6  2020-06-03
#> 7  2020-01-03
#> 8  2020-06-03
#> 9  2020-01-03
#> 10 2020-01-03
#> 11 2020-01-03
#> 12 2020-01-03
#> 13 2020-01-03
#> 14 2020-06-03
#> 15 2020-06-03
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! Sorry about that - I went back and added a sample of my data frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mutate`and `case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(Date = case_when( 
  Date == "2020-06-04" ~ "2020-06-03", 
  Date == "2020-06-19" ~ "2020-06-18", 
  Date == "2020-07-12" ~ "2020-07-28"))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   Plot [2]
  Plot  Date       Cover
  <chr> <chr>      <int>
1 A1    2020-06-03    12
2 A1    2020-06-18    34
3 A1    2020-07-28    17
4 A2    2020-06-03     2
5 A2    2020-06-18    50
6 A2    2020-07-28     3
```